# How can I remove 6-8 inches of concrete from a wooden floor?

Tags: concrete, floor

I have inherited a 143 year old building.  Somewhere in the past someone poured 6 to 8 inches of concrete over top the wood bathroom floor.  I really want the weight out of the building.  Any ideas on a way to remove it? I expect to replace the original floor when I get down to it.  Floor joists are still good and solid, would like to keep them that way.

Comment: lightweight concrete is sometimes used over top of wood floors in multi-story buildings as a fire break.

Answer (score 1):

Rent a concrete saw, make cuts more than halfway through it (preferably within an inch of the wooden floor) in a grid pattern, insert prybar in cuts, break chunks loose. Once you get the first chunk out, pry towards the hole.